# How to clear dropdown of unselected cart button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a repeater which has 3 products with 3 separate quantity dropdown and cart buttons.

1. item1 --Quantity dropdown -- cart button
2. item2 --Quantity dropdown -- cart button
3. item3 --Quantity dropdown -- cart button

So when I click the cart button of item1, I have to alert the value of quantity 1 and blank out quantity 2 and 3. Below is my code. I'm able to alert value but unable to blank the other quantity values.

```
var ddl = $(this).closest('div').find('select');
var selectedValue = ddl.val();

alert(selectedvalue)`
```

[image: This is how the page looks like]

This is how the page looks like

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048227/multiple-cart-button-with-quantity-dropdown-under-a-repeater This is my actual question.

Comment: Can you please post the code to produce the issue. This makes assisting you much easier.

Comment: if this "select" is class then you can blank quantities of those items that does not have class select.. Better if you post code or some pic

Comment: Added the picture and code reference